# How to cancel long output in the terminal?

Tags: bash, git, terminal, output, git-log

How to exit from the long output of a terminal command or a git command like `git log` or `git branch -a`?

How to avoid that I have to press enter untill the output of the command is complete?

Comment: Q, assuming you've got a pager (the program which pauses the output for you, usually `less`)

Comment: Really confused as to why this was closed as off topic

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`git log` uses `more` or `less` for paging the output.

You can press `q` to stop more/less and drop the remaining output.

Comment: more or less but less is more

Comment: Fun fact: You can pipe `git log` and `git show` to `less` in such a way as to start at the first instance of `<string>` and move through output with `n`: `git log -1000 | less +/<string>`. Same works for `git show`: `git show <commit> | less +/<string>`. Just kind of fun since we're talking about it.

Comment: If the output is bigger than the pipe buffer, "q" will break the pipe and usually ends the first process which encounter output error.

Answer (score -3):

Ctrl-C is the entire answer, though it's too short to go in this field.

Comment: 'q' is working for me. Ctrl-C doesn't do anything. Not sure why.

Comment: @mrb is right--it's because you're inside a pager.

Comment: At least under Window 7, using Ctrl+C brings back the prompt and makes it look like the data output has quit, however the data output will resume as soon as you press enter.

Comment: No. 'q' is the entire answer. Ctrl+C has the effect that Tolga describes.